# Functional puzzle: find $f(2)$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

Here's a little puzzle I came up with, for anyone who wants to try it:

> A function $f$ satisfies
>   $$f(x)=xf(x^2-3)-x$$
>   for all $x$. What is the value of $f(2)$?

Comment: Of course, there's the broader question: can such a function exist?

Answer (score 9):

We remark that $f$ is odd, as we plainly have $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Letting $x=2$ yields $$f(2)=2f(1)-2$$

Letting $x=1$ yields $$f(1)=f(-2)-1=-f(2)-1$$

Combining yields $$f(2)=-2f(2)-2-2\implies 3f(2)=-4\implies \boxed {f(2)=-\frac 43}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{aligned}
f(2) &= 2f(1)-2 \\
f(1) &= f(-2)-1 \\
f(-2) &= -2f(1)+2\\
\end{aligned}$$
The second and third equation can be solved simultaneously to get
$$f(1)=\frac{1}{3}, f(-2)=\frac{4}{3}.$$
Therefore, $\displaystyle f(2)=-\frac{4}{3}$.